# Email class - CodeIgniter PHP - Send email to multiple members

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mailing-list

I have been trying to send an email to multiple members within my database. I managed to get the application to send one email to specific users emails, but when I use a list function I get errors (undefined index) that are supposedly in the libraries/email.php file but as far as I am aware I should not have to change the email library file. I am working on my localhost and here is the code:

```
 function send(){
    $this->load->model('mail_model', 'emails');
    $emails=$this->emails->get_emails();

    foreach($emails as $row){

        if($row['email']){
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('myemail@test.com', 'my name');
            $this->email->to($row['email']);
            $this->email->subject('Test multiple receivers');
            $this->email->message('Test');
            $this->email->send();
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            $this->email->clear();

            $path = $this->config->item('server_root');
        }

        if($this->email->send())
        {       
            //echo 'Your email was sent.';
            $data['main_content'] = 'signup_confirmation';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }

        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
```

I have already autoloaded the email library in the config files. This is the code from the model:

```
 class Mail_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function get($id = null) 
    {
        $this->db->select('mailing_member_id', 'mailing_list_id', 'email_address');
        $this->db->from('mailing_members');
        if (!is_null($id)) $this->db->where('mailing_member_id', $id);
        $this->db->order_by('mailing_member_id', 'desc');
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model's `get()`method returns an object instead of an array. Try:

```
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Also, you need `$row['email_address']`not `$row['email']` for the `if`statement.